# How do I create a Twig override for server 500 error?

Tags: theming, 8

How do I override the template used for a 500 error?
Is there any way to achieve this from a module?

Comment: error 500 is server error. drupal doesn't compe to play at all.

Answer (score 4):

This cannot be done in Drupal as a 500 error is a server error. Drupal will never be reached.

However, if you can configure the server, you can accomplish this yourself. This may also work from the .htaccess level in Drupal. I suggest trying it at the server level first if you can.

If you are running Apache, you can use [custom ErrorDocument directives](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html).

If you are running Nginx, see [How To Configure Nginx to Use Custom Error Pages on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-to-use-custom-error-pages-on-ubuntu-14-04).

Comment: This isn't strictly true - Drupal actually throws a 500 itself when it hits an unrecoverable fatal exception (line 269 of errors.inc), and sets the content of the response (the familiar _The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later._ message), bypassing the server's default 500 response page. So theoretically you _can_ override it, even with a Twig file. What makes it less than sensible to do so is that invoking the parts of the page build responsible for rendering the template may actually be the cause of the exception, so you'll end up going round in circles

Comment: Actually replace _isn't strictly true_ with _may not be strictly true, depending on whether the OP means a 500 response that the server has thrown specifically, e.g. when there's a Syntax error in .htaccess on Apache, or whether they mean PHP errors that have resulted in a 500 response from Drupal_

Comment: @Clive, I think the OP means the second, because the first normally doesn't happen after successfully setting up the server environment. For D8 to change the 500 response you need an exception subscriber with a priority higher than the default exception subscriber, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/235602/how-do-handle-exceptions